# ios swift 2 post on facebook page on behalf of the page

Tags: swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, swift2, xcode7

facebook provided the below code to post on to a page, however i am unable to find a swift version of the code also considering facebook has moved to FBSDKGraphRequest v2.6

```
NSDictionary *params = @{
  @"message": @"This is a test message",
};
/* make the API call */
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                               initWithGraphPath:@"/{page-id}/feed"
                                      parameters:params
                                      HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                      id result,
                                      NSError *error) {
    // Handle the result
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This get's the job done

```
let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "page-id/feed", parameters: ["Message" : "Hello there"], HTTPMethod: "POST")

    request.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) in
        //Handle the request
    }
```

You can setup you params with whatever you want. Read about the params here: [FBSDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/page/feed)

Read more here: [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview)

Comment: Thanks @Joakim, I tried the above code but the message doesn't get posted to the facebook page, I've also read through the documentation am I missing something

Comment: Sorry..wrong code. This will get a page feed. Though the params a wrong. I will make an edit

Comment: This code will now publish a post by behalf of a page. Remember to have a valid access token and correct parameters. Earlier the code didn't do a POST request, so it failed.But now it does

Comment: do I need to pass the access token within parameters as for eg ["Message" : "Hello there","access_token":"generated-access-token"]